# JavaScript - How to make the snake grow three squares instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been programming a Snake game in JavaScript, and I'm wondering how to get the snake to grow more than one square when eating an apple, instead of one, preferably three squares.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var score = 0;

var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Teal";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, width);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};

var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.font = "20px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 50, 50);
};

var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
};

var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};
Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(5, 5),
    new Block(5, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];

  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};
Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};
Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;
  if (this.direction === "right") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "down") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === "left") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "up") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};
Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }


  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
  } else if (newDirection === "stop") {
    gameOver();
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};
var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};

Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};
Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};
var directions = {
  35: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

var apple = new Apple();
var snake = new Snake();

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Amadan, changing `score++` to `score += 3` makes the score go higher than one square, not make the snake grow longer than one square in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
let growLength = 3;
for(let i = 1, last = this.segments[this.segments.length - 1]; i < growLength; i++)
  this.segments[this.segments.length] = last;
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;
var score = 0;

var growLength = 3; //how many segments to grow with each apple
var blockSize = 10;
var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawBorder = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "Teal";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, width);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};

var drawScore = function() {
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.font = "20px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 50, 50);
};

var gameOver = function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = "60px Courier";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
};

var Block = function(col, row) {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};

Block.prototype.drawSquare = function(color) {
  var x = this.col * blockSize;
  var y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};

Block.prototype.drawCircle = function(color) {
  var centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  var centerY = this.row * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};
Block.prototype.equal = function(otherBlock) {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(5, 5),
    new Block(5, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];

  this.direction = "right";
  this.nextDirection = "right";
};
Snake.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
  }
};
Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;
  if (this.direction === "right") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "down") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
  } else if (this.direction === "left") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
  } else if (this.direction === "up") {
    newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
  }
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    for(let i = 1, last = this.segments[this.segments.length - 1]; i < growLength; i++)
      this.segments[this.segments.length] = last;

    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop();
  }
};
Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function(head) {
  var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
  var topCollision = (head.row === 0);
  var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  var bottomCollision = (head.row === heightInBlocks - 1);

  var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

  var selfCollision = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollision = true;
    }
  }


  return wallCollision || selfCollision;
};

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(newDirection) {
  if (this.direction === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
    return;
  } else if (newDirection === "stop") {
    gameOver();
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};
var Apple = function() {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};

Apple.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
};
Apple.prototype.move = function() {
  var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};
var directions = {
  35: "stop",
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

var apple = new Apple();
var snake = new Snake();

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color: #FFFFFF"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```